# list all dependencies of maven project

Tags: jenkins, grep, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

I have a maven project(A) which depends on multiple other maven projects(B,C,D,...J)). During development of A, pom refers to snapshot of B,C,D etc. When is time for release of A, CM team needs to release all of B,C,D..J before releasing A.

Developers of A are not able to comprehend the time required to release all dependencies before releasing A. So during CI builds, I want to keep reminding them with the list of SNAPSHOT dependencies that needs to be released first. what is the best way to generate this list in Jenkins? I want the list to be provided as output of Jenkins as well as in email.
It will be nice if the list contains all the snapshot dependencies of B,C,D..J as well.

I tried dependency:analyze and dependency:tree but I didn't get the results that I anticipated.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
I used mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:::*-SNAPSHOT and it spits out all the snapshot dependencies of all modules as part of the build logs; Because it is hidden within the build logs, no one is going to dig through it. The modules have also thrown the same depedencies; Is there a way I can grep these and put into a single file in Jenkins that dev can view? Preferably like a button click next to "build now" button in Jenkins( now am asking for the moon huh!? Well that's what the team wants and I need to give it to them)